# Providing "Either" option in a discrete choice question in a questionnaire survey

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, proportion

I am currently preparing a questionnaire survey where I show few road crossing scenarios to respondents. In every scenario there are two routes to cross the road. Respondents are asked to choose either Route 1 or Route 2 in each scenario. In this case, it is simple to do two groups proportion tests for two different scenarios (for example, comparing the proportion of people choosing route 1 in Scenario 1 vs proportion choosing route 1 in Scenario 2).

Now I am thinking whether or not I should include a third option "either route is okay" as some respondents may have no preference. However, if I include a third option i.e. "either route is okay", I am not sure how to prove that whether or not there is a difference between proportion of respondents choosing route 1 in Scenario 1 vs Scenario 2. Could anyone help?

Scenario 1
[image]

Scenario 2
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to highlight.

- If you want to prove that given two choices, people will prefer one route rather than another, simply stick to two choices, and do not give them a third alternative. Keep in mind though that this result may be biased, especially if they actually do not have any preference, as you are forcing a choice. You might face phenomenons such as people ticking only the first box, because they do not care of the route chosen.
- If you want to prove that there is a real preference for a route (or not), it might be better to propose the three choices. You will reduce bias as you offer to choose the third alternative, and thus you will get more reliable results. If most people chose the option "neither", this simply means that they do not have a preferred route.

Comment: That was helpful. I wanted to ask one more thing, is there a way to show that the route preferences between scenario 1 and scenario 2 are "statistically" different or not, especially when I provide three choices?
Can I use chi-square test (sorry, this is just a random guess)?

Comment: Chi-square test is definitely adapted for this kind of situation, since you will have a contingency table with two lines (scenario A, B) and two-three columns (route 1, 2, either).